# Need to remove ruby array brackets

Tags: ruby

**I have an array like**

```
Array = ["1","2","3"]
```

And I need result like

```
"1,2,3"
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the array like that?

Comment: what you want is not an object.

Comment: Try ["1", "2", "3"].map{ |val| "'#{val}'" }.join(', ')

Answer (score 3):

The name of that operation is to 'convert an array to a list'.

It can be done by splat operator (`*`):

```
array = ["1","2","3"]

*array
```

Hovewer it's hard to demonstrate, because you can not print lists in irb.

OR

You just want to print the array with added brackets. If so, that line of code could help:

```
array = ["1","2","3"]

print array.map{ |item| "\"#{item}\"" }.join(', ')
```

It adds brackets (by escaping `"` symbol) to each array element and then joins the elements by comma.

Answer (score 0):

You expect string ?

```
array = ["1","2","3"]

new = array.join(',')
#=> "1,2,3"
```

Comment: Doesn't have quotes around the individual elements or the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
> puts array.join(',').gsub(/(\d)/, '\'\1\'')
#=> '1','2','3'
```